# What does this error mean in the contex of import excel data into a Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, excel, import

After choosing 'Range Type:' Table Range and 'Select Range:' Sheet1!Table1

I get the error pop-up 'Import to Windows SharePoint Services list' 'Cannot connect to the server at this time. Your table cannot be published.'

Is there somewhere in my computer I can look at for more information as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Event viewer.  Right click my computer then select manage.

Comment: Are you sure that Excel will write out errors like this to the Event log?

Comment: Its not going to give you a developer stack trace.  He asked for more information